# Amount of rows missing after rowSums

Tags: r

After using the this code it shows me that the data has zero row. Why does it happen?

> total$total_sum <- rowSums(total[, c('sume', 'sums')], na.rm=FALSE)

> nrow(total$total_sum)

NULL

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should provide a [minimal reproducible example of your code and data along with relevant errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there might be an issue with the total data frame or the columns you're trying to sum. If the result is showing zero rows, it could be due to missing or NA values in both the 'sume' and 'sums' columns for all rows.

You might want to check if there are any missing values in those columns:

```
# Check for NA values in 'sume' and 'sums'
missing_values <- total[, c('sume', 'sums')] %>% sapply(function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
print(missing_values)
```

If both 'sume' and 'sums' have a lot of missing values, it could explain why the row sums result in zero rows. You might need to handle or impute the missing values before calculating the row sums.

Additionally, you can check the structure of your data frame with:

```
str(total)
```

This will give you information about the data types and the structure of your data, helping you identify any potential issues.

Comment: it has zero missings and the str(total$total_su) shows  num [1:159] 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 3 ...

Answer (score 0):

`nrow` will only take data.frames as arguments. In `nrow(total$total_sum)`, you are feeding it a vector. See the example:

```
nrow(iris$Sepal.Length)
NULL

nrow(iris)
[1] 150

length(iris$Sepal.Length)
[1] 150
```

if we use the actual data.frame , as in `nrow(total)`, we will be fine. Otherwise, if using the individual column/vector is a must, use `length`, as in `length(total$total_sum)`